# How To Stop Rotating A Wheel On Mouse Over And Alert Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

How I can stop a wheel rotating On Mouse Over. I am working on html5 canvas and inside a circle a wheel is rotating. I want to stop the wheel on mouse over and alert the value of wheel.

Here is my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;


var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 150;

var wheel = document.createElement('canvas');
var wheelCtx = wheel.getContext('2d');

var indicator = document.createElement('canvas');
var indicatorCtx = indicator.getContext('2d');


var angle = PI2 - PI2 / 4;

var myColor = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  myColor.push(randomColor());
}

makeWheel();
makeIndicator();

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function makeWheel() {

  wheel.width = wheel.height = radius * 2 + 2;
  wheelCtx.lineWidth = 1;
  wheelCtx.font = '40px Pacifico, cursive';
  wheelCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  wheelCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  var cx = wheel.width / 2;
  var cy = wheel.height / 2;

  var sweepAngle = PI2 / myData.length;
  var startAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {

    // calc ending angle based on starting angle
    var endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;

    // draw the wedge
    wheelCtx.beginPath();
    wheelCtx.moveTo(cx, cy);
    wheelCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    wheelCtx.closePath();
    wheelCtx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
    wheelCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    wheelCtx.fill();
    wheelCtx.stroke();

    // draw the label
    var midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;
    var labelRadius = radius * .85;
    var x = cx + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(midAngle);
    var y = cy + (labelRadius) * Math.sin(midAngle);
    wheelCtx.fillStyle = 'gold';
    wheelCtx.fillText(myData[i], x, y);
    wheelCtx.strokeText(myData[i], x, y);

    // increment angle
    startAngle += sweepAngle;
  }


}

function makeIndicator() {

  indicator.width = indicator.height = radius + radius / 10;
  indicatorCtx.font = '40px Georgia';
  indicatorCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  indicatorCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
  indicatorCtx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  indicatorCtx.lineWidth = 1;

  var cx = indicator.width / 2;
  var cy = indicator.height / 2;

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.moveTo(cx - radius / 8, cy);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx, cy - indicator.height / 2);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx + radius / 8, cy);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue'
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius / 3, 0, PI2);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  indicatorCtx.fillText('Prizes', cx, cy);
}


function animate(time) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(wheel, -wheel.width / 2, -wheel.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.translate(-cw / 2, -ch / 2);
  ctx.drawImage(indicator, cw / 2 - indicator.width / 2, ch / 2 - indicator.height / 2)
  angle += PI2 / 360;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function randomColor() {
  return ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
```

Simple Canvas

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:#ffff">
  </canvas>
```

On mouse over the wheel should be stop and value of the wheel at which it was stopped should be alerted

Comment: Could you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

make ctx variable null on mouseover method.

```
$("#canvas").mouseover(function(){
        ctx = null;
});
```

if you want to continue it, then do like this -> onmouse out resume rotating.

WORKING EXAMPLE : https://jsfiddle.net/z61n9ccx/

```
var backup= null;
$("#canvas").mouseover(function(){
        backup= ctx;
        ctx = null;
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(){
    ctx=backup;
    animate();
});
```

Comment: Divesh how i can alert the value on which the wheel stopped